# Rails 5 controller dumping data from database as an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm just starting out in learning Ruby on Rails. I have the following code in movies_controller.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @movies = Movie.all
   end
end
```

and my index.html.erb has a table structure to display the data from the database as follows:

```
<h4><%= pluralize(@movies.size, 'Movie') %> Found</h4>

   <table>
     <tr>
       <th>Movie Title</th>
       <th>Rating</th>
       <th>Gross Revenue</th>
     </tr>
     <%= @movies.each do |movie| %>
     <tr>
      <td><%= movie.title %></td>
      <td><%= movie.rating %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(movie.total_gross) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

The index.html.erb first dumped the whole movies data as an array and then display the data below it in the table structure shown above. Please what have I got wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the = sign from the each block

```
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= movie.title %></td>
    <td><%= movie.rating %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(movie.total_gross) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a extra `=` when you start the loop. That page should look like

```
<h4><%= pluralize(@movies.size, 'Movie') %> Found</h4>

   <table>
     <tr>
       <th>Movie Title</th>
       <th>Rating</th>
       <th>Gross Revenue</th>
     </tr>
     <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
     <tr>
      <td><%= movie.title %></td>
      <td><%= movie.rating %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(movie.total_gross) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```